# org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "attributeid"

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Query to fetch data:
JPA not able to read attributeId table.

-- select query to fetch data

```
select r,a  from data r ,        
Attributes a     
where a.attributeId.type != 'test'   
and r.typeid = a.attributeId.typeid    
and r.deviceid=:deviceid order by r.typeid;
```

-- table1

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "data")
public class data {

@Id
@Column(name = "typeid")
private Integer typeid;
```

--- table 2

```
@Entity    
@Table(name = "attributes")  
 public class Attributes implements Serializable {  

  @EmbeddedId
  private  Attributeid attributeId;

  @Column
  private String value;
```

-- Class with composite keys

```
@Embeddable 
public class Attributeid implements Serializable {

@Column
private Integer typeid;

@Column
private String type;

@Column
private String attributename;
```

Comment: How are you executing this query?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong. It's JPQL not SQL so you have to join with on clause.

It should be

```
select r, a  from data r join Attributes a on r.typeid = a.attributeId.typeid    
where a.attributeId.type != 'test'   
and r.deviceid=:deviceid order by r.typeid;
```

Is the relationship to Attributes oneToOne or onToMany?

The question is why you don't map the relationship but the only the attributes?

Comment: tried same query its not working for me. another query which has the same parameter is working fine  :  "select m,a  from ManualReadType m , Attributes a where m.readTypeId = a.attributeId.readtypeid and a.attributeId.type='Manual' order by m.readTypeId";